# Modal verbs: "would" as a guess

Tags: will-would

I know that "would" can be used in the situations below:

A doorbell is ringing. My mother says:

> It **would**/will/could/might/may/must be John, I will open the door.

"would" here refers to something like a guess: "I guess it is John."

I don't know if "would" can be used as a guess in this situation below:

> I have never learned abroad. In my opinion, there **would** be many difficulties when learning abroad.

Can I use "would" as a guess as the 1st situation above:
I guess that there maybe many difficulties when learning abroad.

Comment: I think Mother would say "It will be John" rather than "it would". But "would" is fine in your second sentence.

Comment: Sometimes, I still see people use "It would be John" in the movies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that that is the best way of understanding your sentence. When we use "would" for a "guess", we are usually making a conjecture about a current situation. (I believe that John is at the door right now.) However, in your sentence we are commenting on a hypothetical situation. (If someone studied abroad, then would doing so be easy or not?) That is a more common way to use "would", and I believe that it is the most natural way to understand its use here.

By the way, "study" would be used more commonly than "learn" in your example sentence.

Comment: "I have never learned abroad. In my opinion, there WILL be many difficulties when learning abroad."
-> "will" is also good to use here. Right? What is the difference between "will" and "would"

Comment: @LEHANH Yes, you can use "will" there; in that case it performs its common role of indicating future time. It suggests less conditionality than "would" does.

Comment: You would say "There will be difficulties" if you planned to study abroad and expected to encounter difficulties - "There would be" if you were only thinking about what it would be like to study abroad.